# C++ Error: Does not name a type, templated class

Tags: c++

I am designing a templated class within a namespace, and I can't understand why I'm getting this error: 'Test' does not name a type. It seems to only be giving me this error for the constructor and destructor definitions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Note: I am doing this for a class assignment and must keep these files set up in the way that I have. I must have a test.h file and test.hpp included into test.h.

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

namespace mynamespace
{
    template <typename A, typename B>
    class Test
    {
            public:

                    // constructor          
                    Test();

                    // destructor
                    ~Test();
    };
}     

#include "test.hpp"

#endif
```

test.hpp:

```
// constructor
template <typename A, typename B>
Test<A, B>::Test()
{

}

// destructor
template <typename A, typename B>
Test<A, B>::~Test()
{

}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

using namespace mynamespace;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
CC = g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic

main.x: main.o
        $(CC) -o main.x main.o

main.o: main.cpp test.h
        $(CC) -c main.cpp

clean:
        rm *.o *.x
```

Comment: Is this a typo? There are two As. `template <typename A, typename A>`

Comment: `test.hpp` and `test.h`?

Comment: Yes, the two As was a typo.

Comment: my bad you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation file doesn’t specify the right namespace, so they can’t find `mynamespace::Test`. If you change it to include the namespace, it’ll work:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
mynamespace::Test<A, B>::Test()
{

}

// destructor
template <typename A, typename B>
mynamespace::Test<A, B>::~Test()
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have simply moved my #include "test.hpp" statement so that it is within the namespace, and I am no longer getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `test.hpp` are outside the namespace since you include the file after the closing brace.

As indicated by other commenters having the implementations split into another file is not common practice for a template, but if you are required to do it that way you could fix it by adding the namespace to `test.hpp`.